# Integral of product of Bessel functions and powers

Tags: definite-integrals, bessel-functions

We know that
$$\int_{t=0}^\infty t \cdot \exp(-p^2t^2) \text{I}_{\nu}(at) \operatorname{I}_\nu (bt) \, \mathrm{d}t = \frac{1}{2p^2}\exp\left(\frac{a^2+b^2}{4p^2}\right) \operatorname{I}_\nu \left(\frac{ab}{2p^2}\right),$$
where $\text{I}_\nu(at)$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind. What do we know about following integral?
$$\int_{t=0}^\infty t^2 \cdot \exp(-p^2t^2) \operatorname{I}_\nu(at) \operatorname{I}_\nu(bt) \, \mathrm{d}t$$
I know following general answers, but I am wondering if they could be simplified for the case of $t^2$ or not.

The First one is from the book "A Treatise on the Theory of Bessel Functions" by Watson:
[image: A Treatise on the Theory of Bessel Functions-Watson]

The second one is from the book "Table of Integrals":
[image: Table of Integrals]

Comment: You could try to interpret it as a laplace transform and then use that the laplace transform of $t f(t)$ is given by the derivative of the laplace transform of $f(t)$. I didn't try if it works and maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Thanks. I did not quite well understood. You mean to consider $\exp(-p^2 t^2)$ as a frequency parameter similar to $\exp(-st)$? How about the difference between $t^2$ and $t$?